# How many ring homomorphisms $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to R$ are?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring. I want to know how many ring homomorphisms $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to R$ are? For instance, if $\phi(1) = 0$, that's the trivial morphism.

My intuition says, that if $\phi(1) \neq 0$, then $\phi$ is unique.

I already saw other answers but from my personal understanding it is still not clear why $\phi$ is unique. My main confusion is, what if $R$ does not have unity?

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. We define $\phi(n) = n \cdot \phi(1)$, where $n \cdot \phi(1)$ denotes the sum of $\phi(1)$, $n-$times. Similarly, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^-$, $\phi(n) = n \cdot \phi(-1)$.

If $R$ does not has unity $1_R$ and $f: \mathbb{Z} \to R$ is a ring morphism, then I would like to show that $\phi(n) = f(n)$, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Then,
$$\phi(n) = f(n) \Longleftrightarrow n \cdot \phi(1) = n \cdot f(1) \Longleftrightarrow \phi(1) = f(1)$$

If $R$ has no unity and $\phi(1) \neq f(1)$? Then there is nothing to do because $f \neq \phi$?

Comment: What's $f(n)$? You say you want to show that $\phi(n) = f(n)$, but you don't tell us what it is.

Comment: Generally, I suppose the argument is as follows: A ring homomorphism $\phi\colon \mathbb{Z} \to R$ is fully determined by where it sends 1. If $R$ has a unit, we require that $\phi(1) = 1$ in the definition of ring homomorphism, so we've fully determined $\phi$. If $R$ doesn't have a unit, then you're free to map $1$ to whatever you like, and since every choice of $\phi(1)$ gives a well-defined ring hom...

Comment: Thanks @BenSteffan! I think that is my confusion. So there are as many ring morphisms as elements of $R$??

Comment: @BenSteffan, you have to have $\phi(1)^2 = \phi(1)$! So it's not totally free.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen ...ah, right. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen $\phi$ is required to satisfy $\phi(1) = \phi(1 \cdot 1) = \phi(1) \cdot \phi(1) = \phi(1)^2$ by ring morphism properties. But if I'm not wrong, it is not possible to say how many ring morphisms are from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $R$, right?

Comment: As it turns out, $\phi(1)^2 = \phi(1)$ is the *only* requirement ("every idempotent gives rise to a homomorphism" - see if you can show this), and indeed once you know $\phi(1)$ then all of $\phi$ is determined. So the answer is "the number of idempotents in $R$".

Comment: Both of my comments are under the assumption from Ben Steffan's comment "If R doesn't have a unit" - more precisely, if you're viewing $R$ as a non-unital ring. This seems consistent with your assertion that the zero map is a homomorphism. The duplicate link seems to address unital homomorphisms. I realise now that this may actually be the point of your confusion - the most common definition of ring homomorphism requires that $\phi(1) = 1$, in which case there is indeed only one.